# Python mockito library spy2 not working with builtins.open

Tags: python, mockito

found something strange.

The basic behavior of *mockito* permits to use spy2 on a function to mock the method only for specified arguments.

Example :

```
mockito.spy2(os.path.exists)
mockito.when(os.path).exists('.flake8').thenReturn("mdr")

print(os.path.exists("folder_that_doesnt_exist"))
print(os.path.exists(".flake8"))
mockito.unstub()
```

Return *False* and then *True* as expected. The behavior of *os.path.exists* is the normal behavior if the parameters is not ".flake8".

But if I try to do the same with *builtins.open*:

```
mockito.spy2(builtins.open)
mockito.when(builtins).open("not_existing_file.csv").thenReturn("test")

print(builtins.open("not_existing_file.csv"))
print(builtins.open("__init__.py"))
mockito.unstub()
```

I would expect *__init__.py* to be open as normal. Instead, this error is thrown :

```
   mockito.invocation.InvocationError: 
   Called but not expected:
   
       open('__init__.py')
   
   Stubbed invocations are:
   
       open('not_existing_file.csv')
```

Mockito seems to expect *builtins.open("_*init*_.py")* to be mocked too .

Do you know what cause the issue ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a bug (if it is doable) or a limitation because `builtins` are usually hard. `builtins.open` actually points to `_io.open`.  After `spy2(builtins.open)`, `builtins.open` is unpatched but `_io.open` is.

Surprisingly `spy2('builtins.open')` does what you want.

Comment: Maybe `builtins` are easy in Python 3? But in Python 2 they were hard.